# Get summary through Microsoft Health Cloud API on minute basis

Tags: api, cloud, microsoft-band

I am developing a health related application on windows 8.1, and I am using the sample code [here](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI) to extract the data through *Microsoft Health Cloud API*.

I am just wondering if I can get the summary on minute basis by replacing the period property with Minute in the Resource URL below:

```
<version>/me/Summaries/{period}?startTime={StartTime}&endTime={endTime}&deviceIds={deviceIds}&maxPagesize={maxPagesize}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can get minute-ly summaries for individual activities, summaries for date/time ranges can only be retrieved on an hourly or daily basis.

Comment: Is there any plans on changing it? Even if the minutes aren't filled in-  I've produced the health bridge app for iOS(which inserts health data into Apple Health), and right now its injecting data every hour- the average.  if it was 6 points in an hour it would look much better.